# Run-time error '-2147023174' (800706ba) and Run-time error '462'

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm alternately getting these two errors on code that has worked without issue for nearly a year. As far as I know, there haven't been any major changes on my machine. Windows 7, Office 2013. The code is for an acronym definer that works in Word based off a lexicon entered into Excel. I'm getting the error on right near the start of the macro:

```
Sub Acronym_Definer()
'Defines Workbook and Worksheet, Opens Excel
Dim xlApp As Object: Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim FN As String: FN = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") &     "\AppData\Roaming\Gartner\AcronymDefiner\AcronymDefiner.xlsx"
Dim xlWbk As Object: Set xlWbk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FN, ReadOnly:=True)
```

It's occurring on `Set xlWbk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FN, ReadOnly:=True)`.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm not happy about going back to a manual process here. :(

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/189618

Comment: I saw that article, but it's solution is to use the object name, which I'm already doing. The statement that's giving me issues is:
`set xlWbk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open (FileName:=FN, ReadOnly:=True)`
I'm already stating I want to use "xlApp."
Additional help?